# Short story or novel section with the word "grimping"

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a short story or novel section that I've read a few times that features a discussion of the word "grimping", in the context of the meanings that attach to words.

If I'm remembering it correctly, the passage is written as a letter or essay by an older male character who is meant to be read as patronizing. The word "grimping" means something along the lines of "unfair", and the character writing about it relates that it was directed at him by a younger female character who is in some way dependent on him. The word itself was one that she and her sister had made up in childhood.

I'm fairly certain that this passage was in a science fiction story, and the characters involved may not have been human. I read it post-2000, and I don't think it is older than 1990.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tracked it down. The word was actually “grimpting”, from [Terra-Exulta](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1011515) by S. L. Gilbow.

Comment: FYI, you can accept a self answer; actually it is recommended...